# What is the relationship between Markov Random Fields and Conditional Random Fields?

Tags: machine-learning, markov, pgm

In [Neural networks [3.8] : Conditional random fields - Markov network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUnyyVgtyA) by Hugo Larochelle it seems to me that a Markov Random Field is a special case of a CRF.

However, in the Wikipedia article [Markov random field](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_random_field&oldid=695876526#Conditional_random_fields) it says:

> One notable variant of a Markov random field is a conditional random field, in which each random variable may also be conditioned upon a set of global observations o.

This would mean that CRFs are a special case of MRFs.

### Definitions

#### Markov Random Field

Again, according to Wikipedia

> Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, a set of random variables $X = (X_v)_{v\in V}$ indexed by $V$  form a Markov random field with respect to $G$  if they satisfy the local Markov properties:
>
> **Pairwise Markov property**: Any two non-adjacent variables are conditionally independent given all other variables:
>   $X_u \perp\!\!\!\perp X_v \mid X_{V \setminus \{u,v\}} \quad \text{if } \{u,v\} \notin E$
>
> **Local Markov property**: A variable is conditionally independent of all other variables given its neighbors:
>   $X_v \perp\!\!\!\perp X_{V\setminus \operatorname{cl}(v)} \mid X_{\operatorname{ne}(v)}$
>   where ${\textstyle \operatorname{ne}(v)}$ is the set of neighbors of $v$, and $\operatorname{cl}(v) = v \cup \operatorname{ne}(v)$ is the closed neighbourhood of $v$.
>
> **Global Markov property**: Any two subsets of variables are conditionally independent given a separating subset:
>   $X_A \perp\!\!\!\perp X_B \mid X_S$
>   where every path from a node in $A$ to a node in $B$ passes through $S$.

Please note if you know a citable source which gives a good definition.

#### Conditional Random Fields

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Conditional_random_field&oldid=695232246#Description):

> Lafferty, McCallum and Pereira[1] define a CRF on observations $\boldsymbol{X}$ and random variables $\boldsymbol{Y}$ as follows:
>
> > Let $G = (V , E)$ be a graph such that
> >
> > $\boldsymbol{Y} = (\boldsymbol{Y}_v)_{v\in V}$, so that $\boldsymbol{Y}$ is indexed by the vertices of $G$. Then $(\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{Y})$ is a conditional random field when the random variables $\boldsymbol{Y}_v$, conditioned on $\boldsymbol{X}$, obey the Markov property with respect to the graph: $$p(\boldsymbol{Y}_v |\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{Y}_w, w \neq v) = p(\boldsymbol{Y}_v |\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{Y}_w, w \sim v)$$ where $\mathit{w} \sim v$ means that $w$ and $v$ are neighbors in G.
>
> What this means is that a CRF is an undirected graphical model whose nodes can be divided into exactly two disjoint sets $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}$, the observed and output variables, respectively; the conditional distribution $p(\boldsymbol{Y}|\boldsymbol{X})$ is then modeled.

### Question

What is the relationship between Markov Random Fields and Conditional Random Fields?

Comment: See also: [What's the difference between a Markov Random Field and a Conditional Random Field?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156697/25741)

Answer (score 3):

Conditinal Random Fields (CRFs) are a special case of Markov Random Fields (MRFs).

> 1.5.4 Conditional Random Field
>
> A Conditional Random Field (CRF) is a form of MRF that defines a posterior for
>   variables x given data z, as with the hidden MRF above. Unlike the hidden MRF,
>   however, the factorization into the data distribution P (x|z) and the prior P
>   (x) is not made explicit [288]. This allows complex dependencies of x on z to
>   be written directly in the posterior distribution, without the factorization
>   being made explicit. (Given P (x|z), such factorizations always exist,
>   however—infinitely many of them, in fact—so there is no suggestion that the CRF
>   is more general than the hidden MRF, only that it may be more convenient to
>   deal with.)

Source: Blake, Kohli and Rother: Markov random fields for vision and image processing. 2011.

> A conditional random field or CRF (Lafferty et al. 2001), sometimes a
>   discriminative random field (Kumar and Hebert 2003), is just a version of an
>   MRF where all the clique potentials are conditioned on input features:
>   [...]
>
> The advantage of a CRF over an MRF is analogous to the advantage of a discriminative
>   classifier over a generative classifier (see Section 8.6), namely, we don’t need to “waste resources”
>   modeling things that we always observe. [...]
>
> The disadvantage of CRFs over MRFs is that they require labeled training data, and they are slower to train[...]

Source: Kevin P. Murphy: [Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/pml-print3-ch19.pdf)